# CVE-2016-2107 Apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ssl

I have 2 production servers both with Ubuntu 14 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 and when I test both servers against ssllabs only one of them is vulnerable to CVE-2016-2107. The only difference I could find is, the not vulnerable server have the following Apache version

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
```

whereas the vulnerable one has the following:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

So my question is, how do I secure the server? Do I rebuild the Apache?

Answer (score 0):

The CVE-2016-2107 vulnerability is not in Apache httpd, it is in the underlying openssl libraries. It would appear that Ubuntu have issued patches as part of [USN-2959-1](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2959-1/), all you should need to do is upgrade your system.

Comment: But my apt list --installed shows me these 
    `libssl1.0.0/now 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16 amd64`
    `openssl/now 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16 amd64`
I thought these release fixed the vulnerability